# Is it possible to get IP address of devices which is discovered using Core Bluetooth when the devices is connected to WIFI already?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ip, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I want a IP address of devices which is discovered using Core Bluetooth. Is there any possibilities to get IP as I want to create TCP socket connection between my iPhone app and external device for two way communication.

Note: Device is connected already in some WIFI internally.

Discovered BLE supported devices using following Core Bluetooth code:

```
{
dispatch_queue_t centralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("centralQueue", NULL);
    CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:centralQueue];

 [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @NO }];
}
```

I am able to receive the Bluetooth supported devices in Central Manager delegate:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

}
```

Can someone help me to get IP address?

Comment: Why not simply use Bonjour over the wifi instead of Bluetooth?

Comment: I need to discover available bluetooth device(Device can be anything like Processor, Speaker etc). Bonjour is not possible at this case.

Comment: You will need a custom BLE service running on the device that your app can discover and that provides the IP address to your app, so if you can put that firmware on the device you can just as easily put bonjour into the firmware. There is no "standard" way of obtaining an IP address from a Bluetooth peripheral.

Comment: My external device is already running with some Firmware which is already manufactured so its difficult now to redesign to add new firmware. Is there any other possible way through application to get the IP address of the discovered device

Comment: Not if the device can't tell you it's IP address. Bluetooth and wifi are completely independent.

Comment: Thanks @paulw for sharing your knowledge. Let me know if there is any possible way to get IP over bluetooth discovery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139478/discussion-between-paulw11-and-abilash-b-nair).